# I can't install request module in python

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pip

I'm new to python. I'd like to use requests module. but when i type in $, the system shows me "invalid syntax" Is the problem lays in the $?

`$ pip install requests`

Returns:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```sh
pip install requests
```

in the command line.

- For Windows, the command line would be called cmd or PowerShell.
- For MacOS, it would be called Terminal.
- and for Linux, it would be called Shell or Terminal. (in which case you might need to call `pip3` instead).

From there, you can do

```py
import requests
```

in any Python file.